# Tomcat 8 metaspace OutOfMemory issue

Tags: java, out-of-memory, tomcat8, metaspace

I'm using tomcat 8 with jdk 8.
Metaspace is set to 1GB which I feel is very enough,I'm getting OutOfMemoryError exception.
I have tryed checking the class (SSLEngineImpl.java:1796)to get what is causing this but it seems that the line in error is not refering to any load of class.
Can any one help on this please?

```
[http-nio-8202-exec-2] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun 
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.recvAlert(SSLEngineImpl.java:1796)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:1083)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:907)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:781)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.handshakeUnwrap(SecureNioChannel.java:350)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.handshake(SecureNioChannel.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1496)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 1):

From the Docs

> Exception in thread thread_name : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:
>   Metaspace Cause: Java class metadata (virtual machine internal
>   representation of Java class) is allocated in native memory (here
>   called metaspace). When the class metadata metaspace is exhausted, an
>   exception with MetaSpace a detail of " " java.lang.OutOfMemoryError is
>   thrown. The amount of metaspace available for class metadata is
>   MaxMetaSpaceSize limited by the parameters specified on the command
>   line . An exception is thrown with details MaxMetaSpaceSize if the
>   amount of native memory required for class metadata is exceeded
>   .MetaSpacejava.lang.OutOfMemoryError Action: If it MaxMetaSpaceSize is
>   set on the command line, increase its value. MetaSpaceIs allocated
>   from the same address space as the Java heap. Reducing the size of the
>   Java heap MetaSpace increases the space available to it. This tradeoff
>   only holds when there is extra free space in the Java heap. Following
>   "Out of swap space" please refer to the "treatment" of the detail
>   message.

In Java 8 and onwards, we can set the initial and maximum size of Metaspace using the following commands:

```
-XX:MetaspaceSize=N  - sets the initial (and minimum size) of the Metaspace.

-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=N  - sets the maximum size of the Metaspace.
```

Comment: Thanks @Yugansh for your answer.
I have seen the documentation and I'm already setting meta space size to  1 GB using XX:MaxMetaspaceSize, but my question was about was classes  tomcat try to do load to get that exception because i believe that 1GB should be very enough